# Sync local and online WordPress installations

Tags: wordpress, git, synchronization

I develop WordPress themes and I use git for version control. I use a git repo for each theme. The most of the time I am fixing and developing themes so I only need to push little changes to some theme. Because of that I only have the themes synchronized but I have differents plugins and content.

Now I want to completely sync my local and online WordPress installations to make any change in local, including create the content and make plugins and core updated.

I have found a plugin that allow to sync the database and media files. But what happens with plugins and all the wordpress core files?

I can make git repo of all the wordpress install, but I don't want to push all the installation because a little change in one theme. I need to track each theme apart.

Is there a way to make a repo of all WordPress, excluding themes, and maintain the repos I already have for the themes?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, my approach has been to create a git repo of all the WordPress files excluding wp-content/plugins and wp-content/themes with the .gitignore.

So then, I have a repository for plugins, a repository for each of my themes and another repository for all the other files. This plus the [WP Sync DB](https://github.com/wp-sync-db/wp-sync-db) plugin allow me to have my local and production environments completely synchronized.

I hope this help someone!